# Huge Okular fonts

Tags: fonts, okular

I've been having a problem for a while now in that I, at some point, accidentally made my fonts in Okular HUGE. (See figure)

Since I don't know what I did, I also don't know how to undo it. I'm using Xfce on a server where I am NOT sudo user and don't have those privileges.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Ps. all other fonts are normal

[image]

Comment: see here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Appearance